# How do I configure AWS MFA for Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, multi-factor-authentication

I want to perform MFA for Terraform so it's expected to ask the 6-digit token from my virtual MFA device for every `terraform [command]`. After reading the documentation:
[cli-roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-roles.html)
[terraform mfa](https://www.terraform.io/docs/enterprise/runs/multifactor-authentication.html)
I created a role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT_ID]:user/testuser"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This user is forced to use MFA by default and I have a configured virtual MFA device for him.

~/.aws/credentials:

```
[default]
...

[terraform_role]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT_ID]:role/terraform-test-role
source_profile = default
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT_ID]:mfa/testuser
```

in my Terraform environment I placed the following:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "terraform_role"
}
```

But when i run `terraform plan` it throws me an error:

```
Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* provider.aws: No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.
  Please see https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html for more information on
  providing credentials for the AWS Provider
```

Comment: Have created a  `.config` file which says about the profiles ?

Comment: @Malice in my `~/.aws/config` file I have only `[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json` contents

Comment: You need to create a new profile for `terraform_role`

Comment: @Malice `[terraform-role]` statement in `~/.aws/credentials` file is a declaration of this profile

Comment: This question is early, however, a duplicate newer one which has more answers is at [Terraform unable to assume roles with MFA enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432717/terraform-unable-to-assume-roles-with-mfa-enabled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to specify an `assume_role` statement:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT_ID]:role/terraform-test-role"
  }
}
```

Comment: once I add the `assume_role` section I get the error: provider.aws: The role "arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT_ID]:role/terraform-test-role" cannot be assumed. any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: You probably need to create an assume role policy for the user that allows it to assume this role, but honestly I'm not following how this solves the original question.

Comment: Where do you put this part?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `assume_role` statement by itself is not a working solution. You need to use a MFA authentication wrapper [aws-runas](https://github.com/mmmorris1975/aws-runas) that eases the process not only of assuming the role but providing support for the `mfa_serial` clause on the `.aws/credentials` file.

In short, there are 3 steps:

1. You'll need to have your `.aws/credentials` file as you have.
2. Install [aws-runas](https://github.com/mmmorris1975/aws-runas)
3. Run the apply: `aws-runas [your_profile] - terraform apply`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to set up MFA enforcement using Terraform.

**This was how I did it**:

I had to use the [enforce-mfa](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-module/enforce-mfa/aws/latest) terraform module:

```
data aws_caller_identity current {}

resource aws_iam_group support {
  name =  "support"
}

module enforce_mfa {
  source  = "terraform-module/enforce-mfa/aws"
  version = "~> 1.0"

  policy_name                     = "managed-mfa-enforce"
  account_id                      = data.aws_caller_identity.current.id
  groups                          = [aws_iam_group.support.name]
  manage_own_signing_certificates  = true
  manage_own_ssh_public_keys      = true
  manage_own_git_credentials      = true
}
```